# How to create a partial background theme using xaringanthemer

Tags: css, r, xaringan

I can create a xaringan theme with a red background using the below code. What I want is for the top half of the page to be red and the bottom half to be white. Does anyone know how to achieve this with xaringanthemer?

````
 ```{r, include = F}
 library(xaringanthemer)
 style_xaringan(
 background_color = "#FF0000",
 outfile="css/customtheme.css")
 ```
````

Answer (score 0):

For this you want to equip your slides with a `linear-gradient` as background. I don't think there's a convenient way using `xaringanthemer` – at least the following doesn't work:

````r
```{r, include = FALSE}
library(xaringanthemer)
style_xaringan(
  background_color = "#FF0000",
  outfile = "customtheme.css",
  background_image = "linear-gradient(0deg, red 50%, blue 50%)"
)
```
````

It is, however, easy to apply the CSS manually. Simply add the following to your *.Rmd*:

````css
```{css, echo = F}
.partial-bg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red, blue);
}

.partial-bg50 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red 50%, blue 50%);
}
```
````

Then add classes to the slides you want to customize using `class: <class-name>`like this

```
---
class: partial-bg inverse
## Slide with Partial background: Color Gradient

---
class: partial-bg50 inverse
## Slide with Partial background: Discrete Gradient
```

This will produce the following:

[image]

[image]